# How to get the all the timezones supported by device?

Tags: blackberry

How can I retrieve all the timezones supported by a device? until now i was using:

```
 TimeZone[] zone = TimeZoneUtilities.getAvailableTimeZones();
```

This is returning the timezones even if not shown in the device timezone list. Please help me to get all the timezones supported by a device. Each device has its own list.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the blackberry platform well; I just formatted the code in your post so that it would be easier to read for other people.

Comment: @Tim Medora ,ok i am stuck with this so was eager to know the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 TimeZone[] zone = TimeZoneUtilities.getAvailableTimeZones();
     String zones=new String[zone.length];
     for(int i=0;i<zone.length; i++)
    {
         TimeZone tz=zone[i];
         zones[i]=TimeZoneUtilities.getDisplayName(tz, TimeZoneUtilities.SHORT) ;
    }
```